# C++ std::set::erase doesn't work

Tags: c++, stl

I have these following variables:

```
vector< unordered_map< char, set<int> > > LNFA, NFA;
vector< set<int> > L_enclosure;
set<char> characters;
int nr_states;
set<int> acceptance_states, NFA_accept;
```

And I tried using this function to remove a certain number from std::set from NFA variable. But if i print the content in it it display even the items that i want to delete. These variables are globally declared.

This is the function:

```
void remove_state(int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_states; ++i) {
        for (auto jt : NFA[i]) {
            jt.second.erase(x);
        }
    }
}
```

What am i possibly doing wrong to not receive the desired output?

Comment: Try `auto& jt` to get a reference, and not a copy.

Comment: "C++ std::set::erase doesn't work" is a rather bad title since *obviously* `std::set::erase` works - it's used by thousands of programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (auto jt : NFA[i]) {
  jt.second.erase(x);
```

The range iteration here iterates by value. You need to iterate by reference:

```
for (auto &jt : NFA[i]) {
  jt.second.erase(x);
```

Your original range iteration was logically equivalent to the following (not quite, actually, but the minutiae differences are not relevant for the purpose of this question):

```
for (auto b=NFA[i].begin(); b != NFA[i].end(); ++b)
{
    auto jt=*b;

    jt.erase(x);
}
```

So you end up erasing the value from a copy of the actual `std::set`. Not a useful result.

You need to make your range iteration use a reference, so that your range iteration becomes logically equivalent to:

```
auto &jt=*b;
```